# Receive WhatsApp messages using Node.js

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, ngrok

I'm trying to read messages from users via WhatsApp api with [ultramsg](https://ultramsg.com/)

and use [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/)

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const PORT = 4000
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running ${PORT}`))
```

ngrok show display  404  error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Setup a webhook route

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/test_webhook', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(200).end()
})
```

Now Webhook URL is : http://your_ngrok_url/test_webhook

Comment: Hello! I know it's not the same issue, but I'm investigating how to send more than one message with the help of the whatsapp api in nodejs, I dare to ask because I read that it handles the whatsapp webhook issue